# Can't see System Monitor

Tags: gnome

I went to my Ubuntu Software Center to download a system monitor, to find one was already installed.  But when I go to see all my programs its not listed.  In other words I can't access it?  What do I do?

Comment: Run `gnome-system-monitor` from a terminal. What happens?

Comment: ** (gnome-system-monitor:21847): WARNING **: SELinux was found but is not enabled.

Answer (score 0):

System Monitor is installed by default.

You can't find it because you probably have some filters turned on in dash or did not click "all applications" there.

You can start it in terminal by

```
gnome-system-monitor
```